# Converting units to metric

Tags: asp.net, ektron

I'm going to be implementing Ektron CMS for a client and they may require conversion of units from imperial to metric for different values. The best thing would be an Ektron module, then would be something in C# I could use, finally a webservice I could access.

Anyone have suggestions or best practices regarding any of those three, with Ektron CMS and ASP.net in mind?

Comment: What values will you be converting?

Comment: among measurements such as ounce, pint, quart, cup, teaspoon, tablespoon, inch to metric ones like milliliter, centimeter, miligram / also temperatures like fahrenheit to celcius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up doing this on the frontend, a benefit being that only one value is stored in this manner

http://hanamidesign.com/lab/code/prototype/measurement-unit-switcher.html
for an open source solution

Comment: addt'l info http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/10/jquery-globalization-plugin-from-microsoft.aspx